# If $P(x)=5x^2-2x+1$, then find the value of $P(1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, soft-question, definition

A visiting mathematician from the university came to our school.

The mathematician (most likely a professor)  wrote the following problem on the board:

Let, $P(x)=5x^2-2x+1$. Then, find the value of $P(1)$.

All students said that the answer was $4$ and explained how they were $P(1)=5\times 1^2-2\times 1+1=4$.

But we came across an unexpected answer: He said the answer is wrong.

He gave the following example as a reason:

What information do you have about $P(x)$?  What is $P(x)$?  What is the domain of $P(x)$?

Let $P(x)=5x^2-2x+1$ be a polynomial function defined by $P:\mathbb R\setminus \left\{1\right\}\rightarrow \mathbb R$, then what is the value of $P(1)$?

The students said that the domain of $P(x)$ is the whole set of real numbers.  But the professor said that's the "largest domain set".

Now what I want to say is, are these things said really important ? I mean, is the Professor completely right in what he said?  Most students objected...

Comment: When you give a function, you have to specify the domain and the law. If the domain is not specified, then the domain of the function will be the largest set for which the function is defined, by convention

Comment: @FedericoFallulacca let $f(x)=0$ and $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ then $f(x)$ is a both even and odd function. Let $f(x)=0$ and $f:\mathbb R^{+}\rightarrow \mathbb R$ then $f(x)$ is neither an odd nor an even function.(another example)

Comment: exactly, you can’t say anything about the property of the function if you don’t specified the domain (and codomain)

Comment: @FedericoFallulaca but your first comment seems different.

Comment: why? I don’t understand the problem

Comment: Mathematics in high school is usually not very formal or rigorous, so one can usually assume $P$ to be the largest set for which the function is defined. However, if you choose to study mathematics at university, then you have to be more formal, and the results of a statement you are trying to prove may change through a small difference in how one defines things. A simple example where this is important is proving whether a function is one-to-one or onto. For instance, $x^2$ is not one-to-one as a function $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, but it is as a function $\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Strictly speaking (going with the spirit of the professor's lesson), the students aren't necessarily wrong (the correct answer is undeterminable, given the information supplied), and neither is $\mathbb R$ the largest possible domain.

Answer (score 1):

Existence of function like is bounded by definition and scope of domains.

So he's completely right when he expects you to probe further before giving such answers.

Mathematics has two aspects one is academics and other is application. From a practical perspective where you want to solve question as fast as possible and move forward, you're right to give such answers.

However from academic perspective, you've to go via theory and scope of domain matters.

In above question, since polynomial isn't defined at x=1 we can say P(1) doesn't exist

If question is modified to ask value of P(1), considering P(x) to be continuous function.

```
  P(1) = P(1-) = P(1+) which gives the answer P(1) = 4
```